# NullPointerException after user input in java

Tags: java

I'm quite stumped on my situation here.
I'm really not sure why I'm getting this null pointer exception.

//here is a method from one of my classes

```
public class UI {

    Registry reg;

    public UI (Registry reg) {
        this.reg = reg;
        menu();
    }

    private void addAppts(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Enter the month for appointment in mm/dd/yyyy format:");
        sc.nextLine();
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the day for appointment mm/dd/yyyy format:");
        sc.nextLine();
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the year for appointment mm/dd/yyyy format:");
        sc.nextLine();
        int year = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the hour for appointment:");
        sc.nextLine();
        int hour = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the minute for appointment:");
        sc.nextLine();
        int minute = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the owner name for appointment:");
        sc.nextLine();
        String ownerName = sc.nextLine();
        reg.addAppts(month, day, year, hour, minute, ownerName);
    }
}
```

//and here is another method from my other class

```
public class Registry {

    private Appointments[] appts;

    public void addAppts(int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute, String ownerName) {
        if (next < appts.length) {
            Appointments e = new Appointments(month, day, year, hour, minute, ownerName);
            appts[next++] = e;
        }
    }
}

public class Appointments {

    private int month, day, year, hour, minute;
    private String ownerName;

    public Appointments(int month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute, String ownerName) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.ownerName = ownerName;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the nullpointer exception error on the last line of the first method.
Any suggestions?

Comment: where is `reg` defined? is it initialized?

Comment: how does `UI` get instansiated?

Comment: show us stack trace, and where you initiate `appts`, i think that might be an issue if this is complete code

Comment: Are you talking about the Exception in thread?
My apologies, I'm still new to some programming words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess will be (assuming this is completed code), you getting `NPE` when you are trying add new entry to `appts` array inside your `Registry` class.

in snippet which you provided, you never initialize your array.

Comment: Oh shoot! ._. I meant to originally create an arraylist not an array so i can work with a dynamic size instead of a set one. Shoot back to the drawing boards

Answer (score 2):

`reg` is more than likely `null`.

If nullness is conceptually permissible then consider using `if (reg != null){` around the method. If it should not be null by the time this method executes, then ensure it's initialised when the object is constructed.

Comment: well in this _specific_ case that line would prevent the error but break the program, it _should_ be initialized by the time it gets used

Comment: That, of course, is down to the programmer: perhaps it *can* be null. It might be some listener which need not be attached. We simply don't know. But saying that, you're probably right ;-)